# Site Template: retain Site Logo?

Tags: site-template

When I save a SharePoint 2013 Site Template, all my modifications stick, except for the Site Logo. How do I save the Site Logo in the template?

Here's how I changed the site logo: I've uploaded it to Site Assets and changed the URL in the site template. When saving, I've checked "Include Content".

Comment: Try changing it using PS $_.SiteLogoUrl = “/path/to/your/logo.gif”; $_.Update() and save site as a template if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What gets saved in a template**
>
> When you save your SharePoint site as a
>   template, you’re saving the overall framework of the site – its lists
>   and libraries, views and forms, and workflows. In addition to these
>   components, you can include the contents of the site in the template,
>   for example, the documents stored in the document libraries. This
>   could be useful to provide sample content for users to get started
>   with. Keep in mind that this could also increase the size of your
>   template beyond the default 50 MB site template limit.
>
> Most of the objects in a site are included and supported by the
>   template. There are a number of objects and features not supported
>   however. The following table provides a quick summary of what’s in and
>   what’s out of a typical site template, or solution.

If you can make changes to your Master page then try this,

> If you don’t want to edit every single WebPart page and/or if you want
>   to retain the ability to change the page title I have another solution
>   for you. My solution is to change the SiteLogoImage node name in the
>   master page. Thus the javascript generated by the PageTitleWebPart is
>   no longer able to change the logo.
>
> Details
>
> Open your master page and find the line starting with:
>   `<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0"` And replace the
>   “onetidHeadbnnr0” name with something else; “onetidHeadbnnr1” will do
>   the trick.

[Reference](http://blog.jonathanroussel.com/2011/01/custom-site-logo-not-appearing-on.html)

I believe you will need a new custom master page not new site template to show changes you made to a site's logo.

[image]

**For More Info check links below:**

[Site Logo Not Changing on Web Part Pages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9706669e-0488-45cd-9cf6-2edfef91f77f/site-logo-not-changing-on-web-part-pages)

[Introduction to SharePoint master pages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-HA102019628.aspx#_Toc275532085)